# How to fix Maven properties from timestamp

Tags: maven

I'm working on an old java project build with Maven and migrating it from an old Maven v3.3.9 to a "not so old" Maven v3.6.1.

In this project there is a property set from a timestamp like that:

```
    <properties>
        <app.version>${maven.build.timestamp}</app.version>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMddHHmm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    </properties>
```

The property ${app.version} is then used multiple times during the build.

The issue is that the build is longer than one minute and the timestamp is updated during the build.  For example the property ${app.version} changes 202309080807 to 202309080810 during the build.

I tried changing the format to yyyyMMddHH and it works but not when the build start at the end of the hour.

Is there a way to fix the property at the beginning of the build and not reevaluate the timestamp ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out and it was not what I was saying.

Maven does not reevaluate the property once it's set.

The build was part of a jenkins pipeline, and there was 2 maven command executed as part of the build.

- mvn clean install
- mvn deploy

So if that happens to anyone, dig through the logs, there may be multiple mvn command executed.